# JavaMail - how to handle attachment/part with MimeType text/directory

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, mime-types, attachment, email-attachments

**Update:**

After some tests and reading, I decided  to **handle "text/directory" as ".vcf" files by default (vCard)**. Seems OK for all cases I encountered so far. fingers crossed.

**Original Question:**

My Android Mail client app just sent a report about JavaMail attachment having an unexpected '**text/directory**' MimeType. I never saw that before and wasn't aware of the existence of such mimetype :/

Questions:

- How are email clients supposed to handle 'text/directory' attachment (or more generally, 'part')?
- How can I create a valid 'test' email containing a valid 'text/directory' attachment (or part) in order to do some test / debugging?

Thanks.

**Some information I already gathered:**

- I found some explanations in [rfc2425](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2425), but could not figure out/understand what my Mail client is supposed to do.
- Also, [rfc6350#section-10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-10.1) states that 'text/directory' was once used ([by iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/text-directory-registrations/text-directory-registrations.xhtml#text-directory-registrations-1) if I am right) for VCard (not sure that, in my case, attachment was a vcard) but this 'text/directory' MimeType is now DEPRECATED for VCard in favor of 'text/vcard'.
  **Could this be the case [my mail client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elementique.messages) encountered**, i.e. a VCard attached to some email with the DEPRECATED text/directory MimeType? Which (old) email client is using such 'old fashioned' mimetype for VCard (if this is the case.. not sure)?

Answer (score 0):

See examples in [RFC 2425](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2425#section-8). E.g.:

```
Content-Type: text/directory;
        charset="iso-8859-1";
        profile="vCard"
Content-ID: <id3@host.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-Printable

begin:VCARD
source:ldap://cn=bjorn%20Jensen, o=university%20of%20Michigan, c=US
name:Bjorn Jensen
fn:Bj=F8rn Jensen
n:Jensen;Bj=F8rn
email;type=internet:bjorn@umich.edu
tel;type=work,voice,msg:+1 313 747-4454
key;type=x509;encoding=B:dGhpcyBjb3VsZCBiZSAKbXkgY2VydGlmaWNhdGUK
end:VCARD
```

Comment: I managed to create different examples, including Base64 encoded ones. I'll handle "text/directory" as vcf files by default. Thanks.